# Always receiving null list from room table

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-room

I have have room table with some values. I want to sum some of that values, but I am getting error. It is in `otherArraySum()` method and it is `NullPointerException`. I am wondering why `otherAmountList` is null and how I can fix that. Thank you in advance.

Query

```
@Query("SELECT value FROM statistics_table WHERE category = 7")
        LiveData<List<Float>> otherList();
```

Repository

```
public Repository(Application application){
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        otherList = statisticsDao.otherList();
}
public LiveData<List<Float>> getOtherList(){ 
        return otherList;
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class StatisticsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
 LiveData<List<Float>> otherList;
 public StatisticsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new Repository(application);
        otherList = repository.getOtherList();

public LiveData<List<Float>> getAllOtherList(){ 
    return otherList;
   }
}
```

Activity

```
List<Float> otherAmountList;
statisticsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
                .getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(StatisticsViewModel.class);
otherAmountList = statisticsViewModel.getAllOtherList().getValue();
otherAmount = otherArraySum();
public float otherArraySum() {
        float sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < otherAmountList.size(); i++) {
            sum = sum + otherAmountList.get(i); }
        return sum; }
```

Logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.moneymanager.MainActivity2.otherArraySum(MainActivity2.java:155)
```

Comment: Please submit stacktrace logcat of the error

Comment: @Zain just edited

Comment: it seems that `otherAmountList` is null can you debug if the Dao query returns data

Comment: How are you inserting into your StatisticsViewModel? It's possible something may have gone wrong at that point. Can you submit your ViewModel insertion code as well as where you are observing changes to your ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by changing activity code to this:

```
float sum;
statisticsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
                .getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(StatisticsViewModel.class);
statisticsViewModel.getAllOtherList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Float>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Float> floats) {
                for(int i = 0; i < floats.size(); i++) {
                    sum = sum + floats.get(i); }           
            }
        });
```